# Second order differential equation with a cross product

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, classical-mechanics, cross-product

I am trying to find $\vec{r}(t)$ starting from $ \sum \vec{F} = m\vec{a} $ where $\vec{r}(t)$ is the flight of a cricket ball. The problem I have is that none of the forces ([Magnus effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect)) that acts on a cricket ball and causes it to drift works perpendicular to the spin axis and the direction of travel.

The formula I am using for this is: 
$$\vec{a}(t) =  \frac{16}3  \pi^2 c r^3  \rho  \omega  v \left\lVert \vec{u}(t) \times \vec{s} \right\rVert$$
Where $ \frac{16}3  \pi^2 c r^3  \rho  \omega  v$ are a whole bunch of constants (lift coefficient, radius, air pressure, spin, wind velocity respectively).

$\vec{u}(t)$ is pthe direction of motion, $\vec{s}$ is the spin axis (which is orthogonal to the seam of the cricket ball). The force operates at right angles to both of these vectors,

I am unsure how to integrate this in order to handle the cross product as obviously $\vec{r}(t)$ travels in its own direction. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: made a correction to the cross product

Comment: You might get better help on the physics SE.  Is $u(t)$ the velocity of the ball?  Is $s$ assumed to be constant and what does $s$ represent?  Why are you taking the norm (the right hand side isn't a vector)?

Comment: thanks, i have added more detail and will x post now

Comment: Crosspsted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287789/2451